# How To Make Type Appropriate For Varying Return Types

Tags: typescript

I use a REST library for downloading data called Axios and it returns data as a type called AxiosResponse as below:

```
export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
  data: T;
  ...
}
```

The data returned can be different types.  How can I assign type type to the returned value so it is type safe when I use it?

That is, my call looks like:

```
axios({...}).then(a=> {setResult(a.data)})
```

where a.data in one case will be a different shape then another. Say for just this instantiation, I want data to be

```
interface car {
   model: string
   cost: number
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `axios<car> ({...})` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default definitions there is no good way to specify the return types. All you can do is use as type assertion:

```
axios("").then((a => a.data as car)
```

The http verb specific versions allow a type parameter, so this works better:

```
axios.get<car>("").then(a=> {a.data}) // a.data is car
```

If you want you can augment the original versions of the definitions to accept a type parameter (you can put this declaration in your project somewhere :

```
import axios, { AxiosPromise } from 'axios'

declare module 'axios' {
    export interface AxiosInstance {
        <T>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise<T>;
        <T>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise<T>;
    }
}
interface car {
    model: string
    cost: number
}

axios<car>("").then(a => a.data)
```